# How to insert a space after insert node

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I want to insert a space after insert `a` node, the problem is the space that I insert is inside `a` node, not after the `a` node.

I have other solution, which is inserting a `span` and putting a space into the `span` node, but i think it should have a better solution.

```
var $preload = $('<a href="url">test.txt</a>');
editor.insertNodeAtCaret($preload.get(0)); 
insertTextAtCursor('\u00A0', true);

function insertNodeAtCaret(node) {
   if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
       var sel = window.getSelection();
       if (sel.rangeCount) {
           var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
           range.collapse(false);
           range.insertNode(node);
           range = range.cloneRange();
           range.selectNodeContents(node);
           range.collapse(false);
           sel.removeAllRanges();
           sel.addRange(range);
      }
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
       var html = (node.nodeType == 1) ? node.outerHTML : node.data;
       var id = "marker_" + ("" + Math.random()).slice(2);
       html += '<span id="' + id + '"></span>';
       var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
       textRange.collapse(false);
       textRange.pasteHTML(html);
       var markerSpan = document.getElementById(id);
       textRange.moveToElementText(markerSpan);
       textRange.select();
       markerSpan.parentNode.removeChild(markerSpan);
    }
};



function insertTextAtCursor(text, moveTheCursor) {
    var sel, range, html;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);
                if(moveTheCursor){
                    range.setStartAfter(textNode);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                 }
        }
   } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adapting `insertNodeAtCaret` to insert multiple nodes:

```js
function insertNodesAtCaret() {
    var i, len, node, sel, range, html, id;
    var escapeHtml = function(text) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild( document.createTextNode(text) );
        return div.innerHTML;
    };
    
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.collapse(false);
            for (i = 0, len = arguments.length, node; i < len; ++i) {
                node = arguments[i];
                if (typeof node == "string") {
                    node = document.createTextNode(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(node);
                range.setStartAfter(node);
                range.collapse(true);
            }
            range = range.cloneRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(node);
            range.collapse(false);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        html = "";
        for (i = 0, len = arguments.length, node; i < len; ++i) {
            node = arguments[i];
            if (typeof node == "string") {
                html += escapeHtml(node);
            } else if (node.nodeType == 1) {
                html += node.outerHTML;
            } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
                html += escapeHtml(node.data);
            }
        }
        id = "marker_" + ("" + Math.random()).slice(2);
        html += '<span id="' + id + '"></span>';
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.pasteHTML(html);
        var markerSpan = document.getElementById(id);
        textRange.moveToElementText(markerSpan);
        textRange.select();
        markerSpan.parentNode.removeChild(markerSpan);
    }
}

function insertElementAndSpace() {
    var aEl = document.createElement("a");
    aEl.href = "http://stackoverflow.com?";
    aEl.appendChild( document.createTextNode("LINK TEXT") );
  
    insertNodesAtCaret(aEl, "\u00a0");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onmousedown="insertElementAndSpace(); return false;" value="Insert">
<div contenteditable="true">
    This is some editable text. Put the caret somewhere in here and press the button.
</div>
```